# Add text to different columns

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and CSS, while doing so I'm creating a web page which replicates a already existing page that I'm using as reference.

The page that I use as reference has a nice header that contains different text in 3 columns.

I am trying to do something similar to that, however it seems im only able to add text to the first column and not the 2nd or 3rd one.

I'm sure this is possible I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe...

```
<header>
<div>text 1</div>
<div>text 2</div>
<div>text 3</div>
</header>
```

```
header {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

div {
 flex: 0 1 33,3%;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I just had to edit the flex element a little to fit across the page, but other wise it worked really well

Comment: Glad it worked, there's a little typo though, it's 33.3% not 33,3%